# How to handle nan when using isocalendar

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, lambda

I have a dataframe that contains date and `nan`

```
dataframe["date"]
Out[17]: 
0          2019-07-01
1          2019-08-08
2          2019-07-29
3          2019-07-16
4          2019-08-12

1855252           NaN
1855253           NaN
1855254           NaN
1855255           NaN
1855256           NaN
```

I would like to extract the week of each date using

```
dataframe["week"] = dataframe["date"].apply(
    lambda x: str(x.isocalendar()[1])
)
```

but I get the error

```
ValueError: NaTType does not support isocalendar
```

How can I keep NaN in the resulting week column if NaN is present in the date column?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `datetime` type:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['week'] = dt['date'].dt.week
```